# Add a (different) footer to the last odd page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a `twoside` document and I'm using `fancyhdr`. Each even-page has footer 'A', all odd-pages have footer 'B' but now I would like the last odd page to have footer 'C'.

It's no problem to add the footer on even/odd pages and its no problem to change the footer on the last page. But I can't seem to figure out a way to change the footer for the last odd-page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just use: ``\fancyhead[CO]{Contents of the footer}`` directly in the text at the start of that last odd page. This will change all footers on odd pages from this point onward, but since this is last page then it won't be a problem. And in case you want to do the same in the middle of the document, just add ``\fancyhead[CO]{Different contents of the footer}`` on the next page where footer needs to be different. Same can be done for local changes to even pages: ``\fancyhead[CE]{Contents for even page footer}``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example writes for each odd page `\gdef\lastoddpage{<page number>}` into the `.aux` file. In the next LaTeX run, `\lastoddpage` will be set to the page number of the last odd page of the previous run.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lastoddcheck}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \gdef\string\lastoddpage{\the\value{page}}%
      }%
    \fi 
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\lastoddpage}{0}% initialize
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE]{A}
\fancyfoot[CO]{%
  \lastoddcheck
  \ifnum\lastoddpage=\value{page}%
    C%
  \else
    B% 
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Hello World\newpage Foobar\newpage Last odd page\newpage Last page
\end{document}
```

The file needs to be compiled at least twice.

A rerun warning is a little more complex, but more comfortable, because the user knows, when another LaTeX run is needed.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}                     

\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lastoddcheck}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \gdef\string\lastoddpage{\the\value{page}}%
      }%
    \fi 
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\lastoddpage}{0}% initialize
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\previouslastoddpage\lastoddpage
}
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \ifx\previouslastoddpage\lastoddpage
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{%
      \string\lastoddpage\space has changed. %
      Rerun to get the value right%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE]{A}
\fancyfoot[CO]{%
  \lastoddcheck
  \ifnum\lastoddpage=\value{page}%
    C%
  \else
    B% 
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Hello World\newpage Foobar\newpage Last odd page\newpage Last page
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Page 1: B
Page 2: A
Page 3: C
Page 4: A
```

The previous examples were using `\value{page}`, if the page values are not unique, then `\thepage` can be used instead (`\thepage` needs to be expandable):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lastoddcheck}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \gdef\string\lastoddpage{\thepage}%
      }%
    \fi 
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\lastoddpage}{init}% initialize
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\previouslastoddpage\lastoddpage
}
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \ifx\previouslastoddpage\lastoddpage
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{%
      \string\lastoddpage\space has changed. %
      Rerun to get the value right%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE]{A}
\fancyfoot[CO]{%
  \lastoddcheck
  \edef\thisthepage{\thepage}%
  \ifx\lastoddpage\thisthepage
    C%
  \else
    B% 
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Hello World\newpage Foobar\newpage Last odd page\newpage Last page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you see any advantage in your solution over mine (written in comment under question)? I am certainly less experienced with LaTeX, but I think my solution is easier to use and more straightforward. Only "issue" I see with it is that it requires editing source by a user and can not be simply done with external ``.sty`` file.

Comment: @Rafal In your solution you have to know more or less, where the last odd page would be. But in general, this is not thus clear, pending floats can cause additional float pages, there can be additions in `\AtEndDocument` or an index with lots of pages.

Comment: Right, I haven't thought about index and other things you mention. That's good to know. But in a very straightforward document in which last page is "manually" written by a user and hence it can be easily located in the source, is my solution wrong?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, thanks for this very complete answer! It works like charm!

Comment: @rafal, your solution is a good start, but indeed I do not know 'the end' of my document. I do think that it's a proper solution for small documents, though.

Comment: @Rafal A different solution does not mean the other solution is "wrong", it is just different. Depending on the circumstances, one answer might be better than another, but it can be possible, that the other answer is better with changed circumstances. But there is nothing wrong to write an answer. The risk is getting reputation points. :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Goal of my comments was to find out from more experienced person (you) whether my solution has any drawbacks. I am using this solution myself (though in bit different use case) and was curious if anything "bad" can happen while using it, which I didn't anticipate. Often when I write the question on TeX.SE experienced users find issues with code in my MWE (of which I was not aware), so I wanted to make sure my solution works too. Now I see that there is nothing wrong with it. But I can see that your solution is much more robust and universal :)